# Contract.new() promise is never resolved with truffle-contract

Tags: web3js, transactions, contract-deployment, truffle-contract

I encountered a problem with the following function:

```
public async createNoteWeb3() {
   let bank = await this.bank.at(this.bankAddress);
   try {
     let note = await this.note.new(this.bankAddress,{from: this.user.address});
     let status = await bank.addNote.sendTransaction(this.bankAddress,{from: this.user.address});
     let status2 = await bank.addNote.sendTransaction(this.bankAddress,{from: this.user.address});
     console.log('Status: ' + status);
   } catch (e) {
     console.log(e);
   }
   this.getNotesWeb3();
}
```

status2 is just for testing purposes. Normally the first status should take note.address as parameter instead of this.bankAddress.

However when commenting out the "let note" line or rejecting the first metamask request for the contract creation the following two transactions pop up nicely one after another or the "catch" part shows up. But when I accept the contract creation no follow up transaction shows up. There is also no error in the log.

Any advise how to handle this?

(truffle-contract on the truffle dev chain with metamask in chrome)

update:
It looks like that the promise is never resolved if the new() function is successful. If I reject the contract creation the code jumps into the "catch" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like the problem is already discussed here:

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/issues/70